# VBA Excel ListView Checkboxes do not show in Userform

Tags: excel, vba, listview, checkbox

I have a UserForm with a MultipageControl (name Controller_MultiPage).
At runtime my code adds pages to the Multipage and creates a newListView on each page.
Every ListView has:

```
      With newListView
        .MultiSelect = False
        .Width = Controller_MultiPage.Width - 10
        .Height = Controller_MultiPage.Height - 20
        .View = lvwReport
        .HideColumnHeaders = False
        .ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Signal Name", Width:=.Width / 10 * 4
        .ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Type", Width:=.Width / 10
        .ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="I/O", Width:=.Width / 10
        .ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Description", Width:=.Width / 10 * 4
        .CheckBoxes = True
        .FullRowSelect = True
    End With
```

then I populate the newListView with data from an XML file:

```
         For Each node In list
            With node.Attributes
                Set listItem = newListView.ListItems.Add(Text:=.getNamedItem("Name").Text)
                listItem.ListSubItems.Add = .getNamedItem("Type").Text
                listItem.ListSubItems.Add = IIf(.getNamedItem("Input").Text = "1", "IN", "OUT")
                listItem.ListSubItems.Add = .getNamedItem("Description").Text
                listItem.Checked = False
            End With
        Next
```

but the checkboxes do not show. I can see the space for them in front of the first column and by clicking that space the checkbox of that particular row then appears. What I also noticed is that if I change the property

```
listItem.Checked = True
```

the behavior described above does not change, and when I click the free space in front of the first column (checkboxes space) the chsckbox that then shows up is still unchecked.
Any idea?

Comment: Nobody answer so far, but I am getting to a workaround, kind of cumbersome, but that's the best I could come up with. I'll post description an code once tested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the behavior of the MultiPage control.
What I noticed was that if I forced the checkboxes' status (checked or unchecked) from the code, using the `MultiPage_Change` event, then the checkboxes show up.

So what I did was to create a class that holds the status of all checkboxes of all listviews on a single page, instantiate the Class for each `ListView` and store everything into a Dictionary, using the `newListView.Name` as Key

Then when the user changes page, the MultiPage_Change event that fires resets all the values of the checkboxes according to the Dictionary stored values.

In the Listview_N_ItemChecked event some other code updates the status of the item stored in the Dictionary.
Kind of cumbersome but it works.

the class (**updated**):

```
' Class Name = ComponentsSignalsRecord
Option Explicit

Dim Name As String
' NOTE: Signals(0) will always be empty and status(0) will always be False
Dim Signals() As String
Dim Status() As Boolean
Dim Component As String

Property Let SetComponentName(argName As String)
    Component = argName
End Property

Property Get GetComponentName() As String
    GetComponentName = Component
End Property

Property Get getSignalName(argIndex) As String
    If argIndex >= LBound(Signals) And argIndex <= UBound(Signals) Then
        getSignalName = Signals(argIndex)
    Else
        getSignalName = vbNullString
    End If
End Property

Property Get dumpAll() As String()
    dumpAll = Signals
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = UBound(Signals)
End Property

Property Get getStatus(argName As String) As Integer
    ' returns: -1 = Not Found; 1 = True; 0 = False
    getStatus = -1
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(Signals)
        If argName = Signals(i) Then getStatus = IIf(Status(i) = True, 1, 0): Exit For
    Next
End Property

Property Let setName(argName As String)
    Name = argName
End Property

Property Get getName() As String
    getName = Name
End Property

Public Sub UncheckAll()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(Status)
        Status(i) = False
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub CheckAll()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(Status)
        Status(i) = True
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub deleteSignal(argName As String)
    Dim spoolSignals() As String
    Dim spoolStatus() As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    spoolSignals = Signals
    spoolStatus = Status
    ReDim Signals(0)
    ReDim Status(0)
    For i = 1 To UBound(spoolSignals)
        If argName <> spoolSignals(i) Then
            ReDim Preserve Signals(UBound(Signals) + 1):    Signals(UBound(Signals)) = spoolSignals(i)
            ReDim Preserve Status(UBound(Status) + 1):      Status(UBound(Status)) = spoolStatus(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub addSignal(argName As String, argValue As Boolean)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(Signals)
        If argName = Signals(i) Then GoTo bye
    Next
    ReDim Preserve Signals(UBound(Signals) + 1)
    ReDim Preserve Status(UBound(Status) + 1)
    Signals(UBound(Signals)) = argName
    Status(UBound(Status)) = argValue
bye:
End Sub

Public Sub setStatus(argName As String, argValue As Boolean)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(Signals)
        If argName = Signals(i) Then Status(i) = argValue: Exit For
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim Signals(0)
    ReDim Status(0)
End Sub
```

The Form relevant code. Module level:

```
Dim myDict As New Dictionary                           ' the Dictionary
Dim ComponentsSignalsList As ComponentsSignalsRecord   ' the Class
```

for each ListView created, may be one or more for every single MultiPage page :

```
Set ComponentsSignalsList = New ComponentsSignalsRecord
ComponentsSignalsList.setName = newListView.name
```

while populating the listview(s) in a loop for each single item added:

```
ComponentsSignalsList.addSignal List_Item.Text, List_Item.Checked
```

end of each loop, add the Class instance to the Dictionary:

```
myDict.Add ComponentsSignalsList.getName, ComponentsSignalsList
```

Now when changing Page in the MultiPage widget:

```
Private Sub Controller_MultiPage_Change()
    If isLoading Then Exit Sub   'avoid errors and undue behavior while initializing the MultiPage widget
    Dim locControl As Control
    Dim controlType As String: controlType = "ListView"
    With Controller_MultiPage
        For Each locControl In .Pages(.value).Controls
            If InStr(1, TypeName(locControl), controlType) > 0 Then
                Call Check_CheckBoxes(locControl)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Check_CheckBoxes(argListView As listView)
    If argListView.CheckBoxes = False Then Exit Sub   'some ListViews don't have checkboxes
    Dim myItem As ListItem
    For Each myItem In argListView.ListItems
        With myItem
            .Checked = myDict.Item(argListView.name).getStatus(.Text)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

when ticking/unticking a checkbox (note the the ItemChecked event handler is defined in another Class `Public WithEvents`, where the handler calls this method passing both the ListView ID and the Item object) :

```
Public Sub ListViewsEvents_ItemCheck(argListView As listView, argItem As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
    With argItem
        myDict.Item((argListView .name).setStatus argName:=.Text, argValue:=.Checked
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: the two `ComponentsSignalsRecord` Class arrays are not using Index = 0, that is `signals(0)` is always empty and `status(0)` is always `False`.
Also I actually ended up adding a few more properties and methods to the class, since I found this structure of `Dictionary of Classes` useful even elsewhere in my application

Comment: actually `Status(0)` will turn to `True` when checkAll method is invoked, but then again the `index(0)` of the arrays is not supposed to be used

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer to the same problem that I also had and I feel so stupid. I had the first column of the Listview set to Width = 0... and thus the checkboxes would no longer show.
I gave it a width and everithing is back to normal...